# Finding Linux password for beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have an old Beaglebone Black board with a Debian OS installed. I can log-in onto the Linux without typing password via the Cloud9 which does not require password but opens terminals. However, I cannot use the standard SSH nor the root privileges, as I forgot the password.

Would there be any way to recover or reset my password? Is the buffer  overflow technique or something similar usable in this situation? It might be easy to just reinstall the OS, but I wondered if there is a smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

sudo ssh 192.168.7.2

enter host password

hit enter when asked for root@192.168.7.2's password

you're now logged onto beaglebone as root